# Understanding Express.js middleware precedence

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, httprequest

I'm reading the two examples in the [Express.js API reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) but I don't get them.

#### Example No. 1

> Now suppose you wanted to ignore logging requests for static files, but continue logging routes and middleware defined after logger(). You could simply move static() above it:
>
> `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
>   `app.use(logger());`
>   `// other middleware`

How does this cause requests for static files not to be logged? Isn’t *all* middleware executed (in sequence) for every request?

#### Example No. 2

> Another concrete example would be serving files from multiple directories, giving precedence to "./public" over the others:
>
> `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
>   `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));`
>   `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));`

I suspect that for e.g. a request like "/js/stuff.js", the first middleware checks if "/public/js/stuff.js" exists. If it does, this middleware handles the request and *none of the subsequent middleware is executed* (sort-of like an early return). If this path however doesn't exist, this middleware passes the request to the next middleware in line. Is this correct?

**Please explain both examples!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express routes are just a collection of middleware. Every request to the server is passed along the middleware chain.

A middleware function has the signature

```
function(req, res, next) { }
```

You can add middleware to the chain with `app.use()`, as you've seen above.

Each middleware has two choices. It can

- **Pass** the request to the next middleware in the chain, or
- **End** the request chain and send a response

If a middleware fails to do either of these, you'll see your request time out and just "spin" endlessly.

To **pass** a request along, the middleware must call `next()`. The third argument passed to a middleware is this `next()` function. It might have a side effect, like the logger middleware above.

To **end** a request, the middleware can use one of several methods attached to the `res` object, such as `res.send()` or `res.end()` to send a response back to the requestor. So the `express.static` middleware has the behavior that, if it finds the requested file, it **ends** the request chain and **sends** the file. If it doesn't find the requested file, it **passes** the request to the next middleware.

Comment: I see. The key point is that some middleware always invokes `next()` (like logging, cookie parsing, etc.), while some other middleware only invokes `next()` if it fails to handle the request. I think this distinction should be explained better in the documentation.